# Kind of spurious space

Tags: spacing, macros, plain-tex

I'm trying to write a `\spaced` macro: it takes a string as parameter, decompose that string and then recompose it spreading avery token from the others according to a given `\spreadratio`. Here are the macro along with an MWE:

```
\catcode`\@=11

\font\sc="Latin Modern Roman Caps:mapping=tex-text,+onum"

\chardef\box@temp@la=0
\dimendef\dimen@temp@la=0
\dimendef\dimen@temp@lb=2
\toksdef\toks@temp@ga=1

% \boxit is only aimed to highlight the problem.
% If you wanna see the MWE without boxing just comment this
% definition and uncomment the following one.
\def\boxit#1{\vbox{\hrule\hbox{\vrule#1\vrule}\hrule}}
%\def\boxit#1{#1}

\newcount\spreadratio \spreadratio=100

% The interface of \spaced is the following:
%
%    \spaced[<number>]{<token list>}
%
% where the optional parameter is the amount of \spreadratio
% other than the predefined one.
\def\spaced{\futurelet\firsttok\@spaced}

\def\@spaced{%
  \if\firsttok[\let\next\@paramspaced
  \else\let\next\@simplespaced\fi
  \next}

\def\@paramspaced[#1]#2{{\spreadratio=#1\dosp@ced{#2}}}

\def\@simplespaced#1{\dosp@ced{#1}}

\def\dosp@ced#1{{\setbox\box@temp@la\hbox{#1}%
  % the size of the \hbox is changed according
  % to the value of \spreadratio
  \dimen@temp@la\wd\box@temp@la \dimen@temp@lb\dimen@temp@la
  \divide\dimen@temp@lb by\@m
  \multiply\dimen@temp@lb by\spreadratio
  \advance\dimen@temp@la by\dimen@temp@lb
  \global\toks@temp@ga={}%
  \@split{#1}%
  \setbox\box@temp@la\hbox to\dimen@temp@la{\the\toks@temp@ga}%
  \box\box@temp@la}}

\def\@split#1{\@@split#1\end}

\def\@@split#1{%
  \ifx#1\end
    \global\toks@temp@ga=\expandafter{\the\toks@temp@ga\unskip}%
    \let\next\relax
  \else
    \global\toks@temp@ga=\expandafter{\the\toks@temp@ga#1\hfil}%
    \let\next\@@split\fi
  \next}

\catcode`\@=12

\noindent
\boxit{The music}\par\noindent
\boxit{\spaced{The music of Steve Reich}}\par\noindent
\boxit{\spaced[300]{The music of Steve Reich}}\par\noindent
\boxit{{\sc The music of Steve Reich}}\par\noindent
\boxit{\spaced{\sc The music of Steve Reich}}\par\noindent
\boxit{\spaced[300]{\sc The music of Steve Reich}}\par\noindent
% Note that here are no spaces between '\it' and the word 'The'.
\boxit{{\it{}The music of Steve Reich}}\par\noindent
\boxit{\spaced{\it{}The music of Steve Reich}}\par\noindent
\boxit{\spaced[300]{\it{}The music of Steve Reich}}\par\noindent
\boxit{\spaced{The music of Steve Reich}}\par\noindent
\end
```

The result is the following.
[image]

As you can see (note the space before the word 'the') when the first token of the mandatory parameter is a macro (just like `\sc` or `\it`), `\spaced` adds a kind of spurious space before the second token.

I can't imagine where that space comes from, and I'm not able to eliminate it.

Where can be my fault?

Comment: It seems you want something at least similar to the `soul` package. Look up that code and you might find an answer.

Comment: @Toscho yes, but above all I would like to understand where I went wrong without reading one thousand of lines or so.

Comment: With `\spaced{\sc A b}` the token register is loaded with `\sc \hfil A\hfil b\hfil \unskip` because you add `\hfil` after the token no matter what the token is; and spaces disappear, but you probably already knew it.

Answer (score 2):

Your splitting routine doesn't distinguish between letters and commands, so if you try `\spaced{\sc A b}` the final token list stored in `\toks@temp@ga` is

```
\sc \hfil A\hfil b\hfil \unskip
```

as you can see by adding `\showthe\toks@temp@ga` to your macros after `\let\next\relax`.

Of course, the splitting routine also gobbles spaces.

A different strategy is to use XeTeX features.

```
\catcode`\@=11

\font\rm="Latin Modern Roman:mapping=tex-text,+onum" \rm
\font\sc="Latin Modern Roman Caps:mapping=tex-text,+onum"

\def\spaced{\futurelet\next\@spaced}
\def\@spaced{%
  \ifx\next[%
    \expandafter\@spacedopt
  \else
    \expandafter\@spacednonopt
  \fi}
\def\@spacednonopt#1{#1}
\def\@spacedopt[#1]#2{\begingroup\@addtofont{letterspace=#1}#2\endgroup}
\def\@getfontname{\expandafter\@removequotes\fontname\font}
\def\@removequotes"#1"{#1}
\def\@addtofont#1{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \font\noexpand\@temp="\expandafter\@removequotes\fontname\font;#1;"%
    \noexpand\@temp}\x}
\catcode`@=12

\spaced[10]{The music of Bach} This is not spaced

\sc\spaced[10]{The music of Bach} This is not spaced
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: It's a good solution, but has some drawbacks: 1) it works only with XeTeX (and LuaTeX?), as far as it uses an Open Type feature; 2) It leave the original parameterization feature, as far as the `letterspace` Open Type mechanism is a bit strange (letterspace=x where the spreading is x/S with S=fontsize). I'm trying to implement `\spaced` in plain TeX, but it seems very difficult to determine where to expand a parameter and where not.

Answer (score 0):

@egreg says:

> Your splitting routine doesn't distinguish between letters and commands, so if you try `\spaced{\sc A b}` the final token list stored in `\toks@temp@ga` is
>
> ```
> \sc \hfil A\hfil b\hfil \unskip
> ```
>
> as you can see by adding `\showthe\toks@temp@ga` to your macros after `\let\next\relax`.

Well, according to this explanation (and my concerns about parameterization of the macro) I've changed the splitting routine in the following way

```
\def\@@split#1{%
  \ifx#1\end
    \global\toks@temp@ga=\expandafter{\the\toks@temp@ga\unskip}%
    \let\next\relax
  \else
    % here the routine should dinstiguish
    % between letters and commands
    %
    \ifcat\noexpand#1\relax
      \global\toks@temp@ga=\expandafter{\the\toks@temp@ga#1}%
      \let\next\@@split
    %
    % %%%
    \else
      \global\toks@temp@ga=\expandafter{\the\toks@temp@ga#1\hfil}%
      \let\next\@@split\fi\fi
  \next}
```

It seems to work properly, but if egreg did not suggest this system *there must be a problem*.

Is it only a sense of insecurity, or a subtle bug is hidden into the code?

Comment: I removed my comments. You're using the wrong tool: no letter spacing command can work if you first don't take care of spaces between words.